# Lift - Page displays as XML in Firefox rather than HTML

Tags: scala, lift

I'm trying to get a simple Lift example running and I'm having a strange issue. I am using the Sonatype sample list project [here](http://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-scala/tree/master/samples/prj-liftbased/). I modified the HTML slightly, but it wasn't working originally either. The issue I'm having is that when I run the local jetty server and try to access http://localhost:8080 it displays as XML in Firefox 3.6.10 rather than HTML. Note, it displays fine in IE8 but the Content-Type in IE8 is "text/html". I assume Firefox doesn't like the Content-Type "application/xhtml+xml" for some reason. The message in Firefox says:

> This XML file does not appear to have
>   any style information associated with
>   it. The document tree is shown below.

Below are the response headers from Firebug:

```
Expires Thu, 16 Sep 2010 03:55:04 UTC
Content-Length  558
Cache-Control   no-cache; private; no-store
Content-Type    application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8
Pragma  no-cache
Date    Thu, 16 Sep 2010 03:55:04 UTC
X-Lift-Version  2.0-scala280-SNAPSHOT
Server  Jetty(6.1.22)
```

..and the actual response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lift Test</title>    
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Welcome to your project!</h2>
    <p>  
      <span>Welcome to toto01 at Wed Sep 15 20:55:04 PDT 2010</span>
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ajax_request/liftAjax.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // <![CDATA[   
      var lift_page = "F586508075515C1K";
      // ]]>
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas as to what is going wrong? How would I change the Content-Type in Lift for Firefox if that is the issue?

Comment: I seem to have the same problem with Google Chrome as well.

Comment: Adding "LiftRules.useXhtmlMimeType = false" to Boot.scala seems to have fixed the problem by changing the content type to text/html, but I'd still like to understand why the default application/xhtml+xml isn't working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, it looks like the problem is related to the  element not having an xmlns attribute. After changing the XHTML to below it worked fine with the content type as "application/xhtml+xml":

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be in the use of both `application/xhtml+xml` content type and XHTML transitional dtd.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Web_Developer_FAQ

Comment: I tried updating the doctype to XHTML strict and it made no difference.